# How to remove Sort By Name from Magento product listing page?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to remove Sort by Name in Listing page Filter option.

[image]

Please Suggest me.

Comment: I have a multi-store site - how do I change this attribute setting for just one of the stores without affecting the other 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit the attribute with code `name` from `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes` and set the field `Use for sorting` to `No`.